# MongoDB - Mongos instance saturated fast

Tags: mongodb, performance, nosql

I'm using mongoDB with 3 config server, 1 mongos and 3 mongod. I see the server in which runs mongos' instance saturate very faster. It is normal or there are some properties I'm setting wrong? To solve it I have to running more mongos instances and connect to them. Also, there are some rilevant differences in performace to have 2 shard with one node each or 1 shard composed by two nodes?

Thanks for replying!

Comment: Could you describe your schema and workload?  What operations do you run most often?  How and why are you sharding?

Comment: I'm testing mongoDB with YCSB benchmark, which inserts a key (user:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX) and 10 field associated to that key, strings of random char. I load 1 million rows and run the same number of operations, 50% update and 50% read. I'm sharding because I have 30 or more threads and want to distribute the load on multiple nodes.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic, because it is about setting up and managing MongoDB clusters, not about developing applications which use MongoDB. That means this question should be migrated to http://dba.stackexchange.com